# Checking if a number from a list is a prime number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the following code, which should check if the numbers in the list is a prime number or not, but there is an issue I couldn't get through, as I am trying to implementing the optimization of check up to the square root of number, I have a `TypeError`.

```
def is_prime(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return False
    if x == 2:
        return True
    for n in range(3, x**(0.5)+1, 2): # this skips even numbers and only checks up to sqrt(x)
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    return True
    
my_list = [1,2,4,5,6,7]
result = list(map(is_prime,my_list))
print(result)
```

---

```
  File "PrimeCheck.py", line 39, in <module>
    result = list(map(is_prime,my_list))
  File "PrimeCheck.py", line 32, in is_prime
    for n in range(3, x**(0.5)+1, 2): # this skips even numbers and only checks up to sqrt(x)
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: `range` only takes `int`s (or `None`) as arguments. The result of `x**(0.5) + 1` is a `float`... that should be enough of a hint for you to figure out the rest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x**(0.5)+1` is not an integer, so `range` can't generate the list.

Try rounding up:

```
from math import ceil
def is_prime(x):

    if x <= 1:
        return False
    if x == 2:
        return True
    for n in range(3, ceil(x**(0.5)), 2):   # this skips even numbers and only checks up to sqrt(x)
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    return True


my_list = [1,2,4,5,6,7]
result = list(map(is_prime,my_list))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression:

```
range(3, x**(0.5)+1, 2):
```

promotes to a floating point type because of the

```
x**(0.5)
```

For your desired behavior you need to make it an int again, try:

```
range(3, int(round(x**(0.5)+1)), 2):
```

Where

```
int(x)
```

tells python you want to interpret x as an integer type

and

```
round(x)
```

returns the closest integer to x.

Note that rounding may not be what you expect:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Check a number in a list if that number is a prime number and append the prime number to a list.