# Does this code make sense? Prime numbers in Python

Tags: python, math, numbers

```
def prime_checker(num):
    if num <=1:
        print('Not Prime')
    elif num == 2:
        print('Prime')
    else:
        for i in (2, (num ** (1/2))):
                if num%i == 0:
                    print('Not Prime')
                    break
                else:
                    print('Prime')
                    break
```

I am super new to coding, just learning the basics. I based it off of the primality test I found on Wikipedia.

I think it works. It might be cumbersome, but it seems to work.

Comment: Try `a = prime_checker(99)`. Does it give the correct output?

Comment: If this code works but you doubt its quality, you'd better post it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @EugenePrimako it doesn't work.

Comment: @roganjosh You are right, I shouldn't have taken "it seems to work" for granted.

Comment: Dang it, it doesn’t work. It says that 99 is prime. Not sure why, the mod should allow it to find 3 and 33. I will keep messing with it.

Comment: I forgot to put range before the ()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a number is a prime number from a list, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42078325/checking-if-a-number-is-a-prime-number-from-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Your question is not clear and seems broad. Please be more precise in what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator for your `for` loop should be a range of integers, not just a tuple of 2 and the square root the number. When using `range`, be sure to convert the bounds to integers with `int` first. And it's only considered a prime number if the number cannot be divided by any of the numbers in the loop, so you should declare a prime number only after the loop finishes, or otherwise the loop should declare "not prime" and returns.

```
def prime_checker(num):
    if num <=1:
        print('Not Prime')
    elif num == 2:
        print('Prime')
    else:
        for i in range(2, int(num ** (1/2)) + 1):
            if num%i == 0:
                print('Not Prime')
                return
        print('Prime')

prime_checker(63)
prime_checker(31)
prime_checker(9)
```

This outputs:

```
Not Prime
Prime
Not Prime
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I just noticed that I completely forgot to put range in. Just a typo.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this question as answered if you think it is correct?

Comment: The lack of range is a typo, but this answer's more important point is not returning 'prime' until the end of the loop.

Comment: @Daniel In which way is it not working? I did test it myself and it works.

Comment: I don't think `9` is a prime number.

Comment: @Daniel Good point. The upper bound of the range needs to get a `+ 1` because it needs to include the square root number itself. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Shnpln I just updated my answer with sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: @blhsing I see it works. I don’t know what the return function does I guess. I literally started learning python less than a week ago. Have a lot to learn.

Comment: Also, why is that last print statement on the same indent as the for. I don’t get it

Comment: @Shnpln This is because the last print statement that prints `Prime` should only execute after the `for` loop finishes and fails to find a number that can divide the given number. It therefore needs to be outside the `for` loop and is therefore indented at the same level as the `for` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is good, however you could have used `sqrt` for root square,
also the `range` function will raise a `TypeError` if you supply a `float` parameter (which is usually the case when working with root square).

A working implementation would be:

```
from math import sqrt

def prime_checker(num):
    is_prime = True
    if num <= 1 or not isinstance(num, int):
        is_prime = False
    elif num == 2:
        pass
    else:
        for i in range(2, int(sqrt(num)) + 1):
            if num % i == 0:
                is_prime = False
                break
    if is_prime:
        print('Prime')
    else:
        print('Not Prime')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it to work not as a function.

```
from math import sqrt

print('This script will check if your input is a prime number.')

num = int(input('Number: '))

if num <=1:
    print('Not Prime')
elif num == 2 or num ==3:
    print('Prime')
else:
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(num)) + 1):
        if num%i == 0:
            a = 'Not Prime'
            break
        else:
            a = 'Prime'

    print(a)
```